# Can I get jquery elements from string which contains some other text?

Tags: jquery

I want to get Jquery DOMs from below:

```
var targetStr = "someText1<input type='button' id='node1' >someText2<input type='button' id='node2'>someText3"
```

I tried:

```
$(targetStr).find('#node1');    $(targetStr).find('#node2');
```

but both doesn't  work.

What I want is to get every jQuery element from string which contains other text.

Any method or plugin would be be very appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand why you're storing this markup as a string in a variable

Comment: Can you change to targetStr to this? `var targetStr = "<div>someText1<input type='button' id='node1' >someText2<input type='button' id='node2'>someText3</div>"`

Comment: what do you mean by other text?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [parsehtml](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) and [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function):

```js
var targetStr = "someText1<input type='button' id='node1' >someText2<input type='button' id='node2'>someText3"

var result = $.parseHTML(targetStr).filter(function(ele, index) {
  return ele.id == 'node1' || ele.id == 'node2';
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```
$(targetStr).find('#node1');
```

This will allow jQuery to treat the code like usable HTML:

```
$('<div>').append(targetStr).find('#node1')
```